# HTML/CSS: Button aligning bottom when no text?

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem with buttons that are next to an input field, it seems to be stuck to bottom, and I can't find why or how to modify it.

My intention is to put a background image only. In order to identify the button for this question I've added string Text to one button and saw that this problem disappeared.

Problem is that I don't want any description there, IE 8 shows it fine (surprisingly). I'm working on Firefox last version.

I appreciate any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/bmGb5/

Screenshot: http://www.imgx.gxzone.com/images/a/9/a971c01a223.jpg

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't seem to see the problem you're having - can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: I've added a screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a `vertical-align` style on the button. `bottom` will probably work best.

Comment: Thanks, seems that Vertical-align: baseline comes by default on buttons. If I align it to top, then keeps misaligned with the other elements by 0.5px (for what I saw) so I had to add vertical-align to the other elements (input field and select)

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top{}` and `margin-bottom{}` respectively.